# Altium unmatched nets problem

Tags: altium

I am building a power supply.
I made all my footprints and and my schematic library (if this can have an impact)

Briefly, when I import my change to my pcb board, none of my connection stays and I get a bunch of unmatched nets...

[image: Unmatched nets]

Here is my schematic:

[image]
If anyone could help, that would save me. It's been 2 evenings i'm trying to work this out...

THANK YOU

---

Thank you for your response.

I have tried to recompile and I didn't get any error.
Here is what appeared when said "no" to matching nets automatically and executed the changes:

[image]

It says Unknown pin..., is there a way to modify that?

Comment: It looks like the parts on your PCB don't have proper labels. There shouldn't be a '*' in the net names - but a components name instead - so 'Net*_1' should be 'NetC1_1' or something like that. Are all of your PCB parts labeled with '*' ?

Comment: Hi, no they arent they all have differents names like C1, VR1, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a project -> Recompile (it's in the menu), then open the Messages window and post a list of the error messages you're getting. I have a feeling that what you're seeing is not necessarily a problem.

Perform a transfer from your schematic to the PCB, Altium will warn you that you have unmatched nets. Just say "no" when Altium wants you to match them (Do you want to match those nets manually). This is Altium's way of telling you: "Either you do it and control it manually or I will and do it automatically". In about every case, the automatic way here is the better one.

You will then get an ECO changelist which basically tells you what changes Altium will perform. It will probably delete the nets with the asterisk and add your nets. Confirm the dialog with "Execute". You should actually get correct net names without having to match any of them manually.

If you want to debug, add a net label to any of your nets, Project -> Recompile -> Watch for errors in the messages window. If none, transfer to PCB, you should now see at least the net you added (the name of the net label).

Comment: Hi, I do not get any error while I'm doing the "recompile".

Comment: However, I do get errors while executing the changes. It says "Unknown pins" at many places. I can't put an image though, i'm having a hard time... I'll post an answer to show you

Comment: The "Unknown pin" error is typical if you have made changes to your component footprint _after_ you first added them to the PCB Layout. Try a Tools -> Update Components from Libraries.